# OCaml understanding begin and end

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

So I am currently writing a function to draw a line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) by modifying an image, which stores its with, height and a 2d array of pxiels.

```
let drawLine image colour start finish =
    match (image, start, finish) with
    |(Image ((w,h), pixels),(x0, y0), (x1, y1)) -> 
                         let dx = abs(x1 - x0) in
                         let dy = abs(y1 - y0) in
                         let sx = Bool.to_int (x0 < x1) in
                         let sy = Bool.to_int (y0 < y1) in
                         let err = (dx - dy) in

                         let rec inner x y myErr =  
                             begin
                                 let xx = ref x in
                                 let yy = ref y in
                                 let ERR = ref myErr in

                                 pixels.(!yy).(!xx) <- colour;

                                 if not (xx = x1 && yy = y1) then begin
                                     if (!ERR * 2 > -dy) then begin
                                         ERR := !ERR - dy
                                         xx := !xx + sx
                                     end
                                     if (!ERR * 2  < dx) then begin
                                         ERR := !ERR + dx;
                                         yy := !yy + sy
                                     end
                                     inner !xx !yy !ERR
                                 end
                             end
                            
                                                         
                        in inner x0 y0 err
```

Now I am certain that there are better ways of doing this but the main thing I am concerned about is the if ... then begin ... end blocks. I'm not used to using them and they seem to be causing me some trouble. When I run the program as above I get [the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdjyW.png). I have tried adding semicolons after the ends but then new errors pop up, I just want to know how to fix my syntax

Comment: I've said it  few times lately, but a match with only one clause smells funny. You can probably better achieve the same thing by pattern-matching in a let binding, or directly in the function arguments.  `let drawLine image colour start finish = ...` might be `let drawLine (Image (w, h), pixels) colour (x0, y0) (x1, y1) = ...`

Comment: @Chris Note that pattern matching the variant in the arguments would only work if `Image` is the only constructor of that variant, otherwise it would fail to compile with warning 8 (not exhaustive).

Comment: Ah yeah doing that had gone over my head, thanks!

Comment: @VPhantom3 that's a great point. It is equivalent to the code when though, which was equally exhaustive (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Your begin/end pairs look OK to me. In OCaml, `begin`/`end` is more or less identical to `(` / `)` (open/close parentheses), if this makes them any easier to relate to.

The most obvious problem is that you have a variable named `ERR`. Variables in OCaml have to start with a lower-case letter.

Since you don't give a self-contained example, I can't easily tell if this is the only problem. But I would suggest renaming `ERR` to `err` (or similar) and trying again.

Comment: That fixed things thanks!